# Flutter future builder rendering unexpected widget. How can I fix it?

Tags: flutter

The current behavior is if 'auth.isAuth' is false, and I've navigated anywhere other than the HomeScreen, the future builder won't accurately render the AuthScreen. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Users>(
          builder: (ctx, auth, user) => Users(
            auth.token,
          ),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Themes>(
          builder: (context) => Themes(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer2<Auth, Themes>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, theme, _) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Prometheus',
            theme: theme.currentThemeData,
            home: auth.isAuth
                ? HomeScreen()
                : FutureBuilder(
                    future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
                    builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot authResultSnapshot) {
                      if (authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return SplashScreen();
                      }
                      if (authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.done) {
                        if (authResultSnapshot.data) {
                          return HomeScreen();
                        } else {
                          return AuthScreen();
                        }
                      } else {
                        return AuthScreen();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it render then? `Splashcreen`, `HomeScreen` or `AuthScreen`? Can you also show your `tryAutoLogin` function

Answer (score 1):

I think you should always approach the following way to use futurebuilder to cover all the cases.

```
auth.isAuth
                ? HomeScreen()
                : FutureBuilder(
                    future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
                    builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot authResultSnapshot) {
                      if (authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return SplashScreen();
                      }

                      if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
                        return AuthScreen();
                      }

                      if (authResultSnapshot.hasData &&
                          authResultSnapshot.data != null) {
                        return HomeScreen();
                      } else {
                        return AuthScreen();
                      }

                      return AuthScreen();
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Guh, I've figured it out.

At the top of my builder function I added:

```
ifAuth(targetScreen) => auth.isAuth ? targetScreen : AuthScreen();
```

Then right after the future builder I added the ifAuth function inside of each of the routes:

```
            routes: {
              AssetListScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ifAuth(HomeScreen()),
```